# Could not load file or assembly - how to determine correct "newVersion" for bindingRedirect?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-4.8

I'm aware that there are many questions on StackOverflow regarding this subject, but they always provide a solution like "change version X to Y and it will be working". For some, removing bindingRedirect works, for some setting specific version, but I want to know for sure.

So, assuming I'm seeing this error (in fact I'm seeing similar errors for other packages too, this is just an example).

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What should be my steps to diagnose that?

As I understand what is happening:

1. My project uses package X with version `4.2.0.0`
2. My project also uses package Y that uses X, but with another version
3. Package Y tries to find version it needs, but does not finds it as I've got `4.2.0.0` in my project

Now, what steps should I take to ensure I won't have any runtime problems in the future?

- How can I identify which package uses old version of `System.Net.Http` or any other that causes similar error? Can I somehow check which assembly uses `System.Net.Http` with version other than `4.2.0.0`?
- Are there any tools that would help me with that? Can Visual Studio do that?
- When I find this package: should I use bindingRedirect to make entire project use version that Y use?

Comment: _"How can I identify which package uses old version"_ - do a `msbuild /bl` (binlog) and inspect it with the (third-party) tool [MSBuild Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/). Or at runtime: enable fusion logging.

Comment: Understanding the error message is paramount.  This is not a "found the wrong version" message as you surmised, it couldn't be found at all.  Not good.  Get a detailed build trace with Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > "MSBuild project build output verbosity".  After building, copy/paste the content of the Output window into a text editor and search for "System.Net.Http" to get the lay of the land.

Comment: @Hans yeah but System.Net.Http was developed framework-independently, then integrated into .NET Framework 4.5 (IIRC) and was still released as version 4.2.0, then came .NET Standard 1.1 which referenced the HttpClient _NuGet_ version 4.3.0 (which had _assembly_ version 4.2.1) and oh my $deity the nightmares. What it looks like here, is that something here is targeting .NET Framework, and something else is targeting ... something else. I've also had that triggered by MSBuild because one of my deps targeted .NET Standard, which caused an implicit redirect during build of my Framework project.